# Doubts of: TimeOut Error Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I've got a problem regarding the timeout issue, where when I build the freestyle job I get the following error.

What I want to do is to run various RTT tests using the shell script command line parameter.

my code is:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Checkout sws-vagrant') {
            steps {
                timeout(60) {
                git branch: 'master_windows', credentialsId: '1d17027a-34b5-4157-93d8-804d0cd56c0a', url: 'git@bitbucket.org:shipwire/sws-vagrant.git'
            }
        }
    }

        stage('Vagrant Up Environment Stage') {
            steps {
                sh 'vagrant up'
            }
        }

        stage('Vagrant SSH Stage') {
            steps {
                sh 'vagrant ssh'
            }
        }

        stage('Redirect to RestTests directory') {
            steps {
                sh 'cd /vagrant/src/shipwire/frontend/v2/tests/RestTests/'
            }
        }

        stage('Restart HTTPD Service') {
            steps {
                sh 'sudo service httpd restart'
            }
        }

        stage('Run the RTT tests') {
            steps {
                sh 'rtt -concurrency=4 test-plans/v3apis/products/products.rtt'
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

As a Pipeline Script.

What I would like to do is to set my timeout between 60-300 minutes or MINUTES as in pipeline syntax.

When I build my job it displays, the console error as follows:

My Console Error Output shows:

```
Started by user Doga Ozer
[Pipeline] node
Running on master in C:\Jenkins\workspace\checkout-vagrant
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Checkout sws-vagrant)
[Pipeline] timeout
Timeout set to expire in 1 hr 0 min
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] git
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url git@bitbucket.org:shipwire/sws-vagrant.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@bitbucket.org:shipwire/sws-vagrant.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials Shipwire Bitbucket Private Key 2
 > git fetch --tags --progress git@bitbucket.org:shipwire/sws-vagrant.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from git@bitbucket.org:shipwire/sws-vagrant.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:812)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1079)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1110)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:113)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:85)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:75)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:260)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress git@bitbucket.org:shipwire/sws-vagrant.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code -1:
stdout: 
stderr: remote: Counting objects: 2444           
remote: Counting objects: 6663, done.        
remote: Compressing objects:   0% (1/2841)           
remote: Compressing objects:   1% (29/2841)           

Receiving objects:  97% (6498/6663), 346.40 MiB | 366.00 KiB/s   

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1903)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1622)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:71)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:348)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:810)
    ... 13 more
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // timeout
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Vagrant Up Environment Stage)
Stage 'Vagrant Up Environment Stage' skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Vagrant SSH Stage)
Stage 'Vagrant SSH Stage' skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Redirect to RestTests directory)
Stage 'Redirect to RestTests directory' skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Restart HTTPD Service)
Stage 'Restart HTTPD Service' skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Run the RTT tests)
Stage 'Run the RTT tests' skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1):

The timeout command **timeout(60) {//your command}** that you have used is not being considered and the default value is being used and that is **10**.

Instead, there are two ways,

1. you can override the timeout from *Additional Behaviours* under *scm* section and over there you can specify the timeout to the desired value. In my case setting it to **30** solved the issue.
2. You can take help of **pipeline-syntax** to generate pipeline script for checking out the project. Below is sample snippet that worked for me, you can adjust it as per your convenience:

   ```
   `stage('Checkout sws-vagrant') {
       steps {
           checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: 'BRANCH_NAME']], browser: [$class: 'GitBlitRepositoryBrowser', projectName: 'PROJECT_NAME', repoUrl: 'REPO_URL (for ex: github.com)'], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [[$class: 'CloneOption', depth: 0, noTags: false, reference: '', shallow: false, timeout: 30]], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'CREDENTIALS_ID', url: 'URL']]])

   }`
   ```

Hope it helps :)